# Why show me different result when use coroutines in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I starting work with `Coroutines` and show some tutorials from Youtube!
I write below codes, I thins print **10 times** Log message every 1 sec.
But not shown me **10 times**!
Sometimes show me **6 times**, sometimes **3 times**, sometime **8 times** and more ... 
Why show me different result in LogCat ?

**My Codes :**

```
        CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
        val job = CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
            repeat(10){
                delay(1000)
                Log.e("Join", "Show")
            }
        }
        job.join()
        Log.e("Join", "Done")
    }
```

**Logcat logs :**

```
2022-02-03 20:27:13.289 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Show
2022-02-03 20:27:14.289 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Show
2022-02-03 20:27:16.292 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Show
2022-02-03 20:27:17.293 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Show
2022-02-03 20:27:18.294 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Show
2022-02-03 20:27:22.298 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Show
2022-02-03 20:27:22.299 21152-21152/my.app.coroutines E/Join: Done
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running coroutine on the main dispatcher which is the IO thread as well. try using a different dispatcher like IO etc.